# Python's lxml ignores "minOccurs=0"

Tags: python-3.x, lxml

I'm writing a Python script that creates XML data, and then validates it using an XSD file. At one particular place in the XML data, I get a validation error even though things look correct.

First, here's an extract from the XSD file

```
<xs:complexType name="address">
  <xs:all>
    <xs:element name="city" type="string255Length" minOccurs="0">
    <xs:element name="postal_code" type="string255Length" minOccurs="0">
```

I interpret this as the "address" tag can have zero or one "city" and "postal_code" tags. As simplified version of my xml data is this:

```
<address>
  <city>London</city>
</address>
```

I'd thought that this was legal xml data according to the XSD. This is the code:

```
schema_doc = etree.parse(xsd_file)
schema = etree.XMLSchema(schema_doc)
schema.assertValid(xml_data)
```

When I run that code, I get

```
Missing child element(s). Expected is one of ( postal_code )
```

To me, it looks like the XML validator ignores the `minOccurs="0"` statement, thus requiring all the elements to be present.

Does anyone know what's causing this seemingly unexpected error?

Comment: I've also encountered this issue. `lxml` seems to not respect `minOccurs=0`. Did you ever come to a resolution @kenneho? I will update if I find a fix.

Comment: Hi @henrycjc, I haven't worked on this code base since September, so I don't recall what I ended up doing. Let me check up on this in the next few days, and I'll get back to you then.

Comment: @henrycjc, I check the code, and I can't explain it but it looks the same, but doesn't throw any error anymore.

Comment: @kenneho I resolved the issue by omitting the value altogether (i.e. blank line instead of <Value/>